# append data in multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to import my table data into multi-dimensional array in PHP, the table data is continuously updating, so the matrix has to be updated as soon as data is inserted in the table. 
How do we create a multi-dimensional array, insert data into it and then append the data dynamically into the array?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a task?

Comment: Ignore the table, the main problem is how do i append the data dynamically to a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Comment: What do you mean by append dynamically are 1. Add data to array 2. add data if exist replace 3. replace existing data ?? You also need to give example of your multidimensional array structure ...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you got a "normal" one-dimensional array out of your table.
To make a multidimensional-array out of it, you have to put the one-dimensional array into a multidimensional array.
To do this, you could use something like:

```
$i = 0; //initialize i
while ($i < count($array)) { //as long as i is smaller than the array
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) { //walk along the array
        $newArray[$i][$key] = $value; // set the multidimensional array
    }
    $i++; // count one up 
}
```

With this, you should get a multidimensional array looking like:

```
array(
      '0' => array(
                    '0' => 'foo'
                    '1' => 'bar'
                  )
      '1' => array(
                    '0' => 'foo'
                    '1' => 'bar'
                  )
     )
```

and so on... hope this helps

Comment: After inserting the data, can i append a new 2=>'card' in the 0=>array() part??

Comment: sure, do you want to append or update the key 2? When you want to append, just use $newArray[] => 'card'. If you want to update (overwrite), use $newArray[2] => 'card'

Comment: Tom, the scenario is i am maintaining a table for term frequency in the documents, so my column1 will be the different terms in all the documents, and a new column is added for every new document and is inserted with the respective term count, and if it has any new term; the column1 has to be updated and the updated row has to be made null for the previous columns.so if I create a matrix initially, when the table is updated, i need to update the matrix too, here my matrix dimensions may be really huge.Suggest me some solution? BTW i need the matrix to calculatethe dotproduct with the userquery

Comment: I think, I don't know what you exactly want to do. Could you please post an example? As far as I got it, I would advise you to do this with objects. Write a document object, which has one or more term-objects.

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do i think should should look at objects approach because form the following comments

> Tom, the scenario is i am maintaining a table for term frequency in the documents, so my column1 will be the different terms in all the documents, and a new column is added for every new document and is inserted with the respective term count, and if it has any new term;

I can identify the following

- Team
- Document

Rather than make document null only update the required team information

Example

```
// Porpulate Teams
$teams = array_map(function ($v) {return new Team($v);}, range("A", "Z"));

// Porpulate Documents
$doc = new SplObjectStorage();
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++) {
    $doc->attach(new Document($teams[array_rand($teams)]));
}

usort($teams, function($a,$b){ return $b->frequency - $a->frequency;});

//Top 10 Teams
echo "<pre>";
foreach (array_slice($teams, 0,10) as $team ) {
    echo "Team ", $team->name, "\t", $team->frequency, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
Team P  9
Team N  8
Team S  7
Team Q  6
Team M  6
Team D  6
Team O  5
Team G  5
Team K  5
Team F  5
```

Class Used

```
class Document {
    function __construct(Team &$team) {
        //Do your metrix
        $team->frequency ++;
    }
}

class Team {
    public $name;
    public $frequency = 0;
    function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```